# Disable compression of author-year citations in natbib

Tags: natbib

I would like to disable the compression of author-year citations in `natbib`. For example, the following source code generates the output "[Miller, 2001, 2002]":

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{meyer2001,
  title = {foo},
  year = {2001},
  author = {K. Miller},
  journal = {Nature}
}
@article{meyer2002,
  title = {bar},
  year = {2002},
  author = {K. Miller},
  journal = {Science}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\citep{meyer2001,meyer2002}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

However, I would like to have the output "[Miller, 2001, Miller, 2002]" instead. I would be glad for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

Consider to switch to [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{meyer2001,
title = {foo},
year = {2001},
author = {K. Miller},
journal = {Nature},
}
@article{meyer2002,
title = {bar},
year = {2002},
author = {K. Miller},
journal = {Science},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\autocite{meyer2001,meyer2002}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]